# Ember.js / Ember Data - Render hasMany key/value pair in template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `Document` model, which has attributes/properties defined to it using a `hasMany` relationship. The purpose is to freely be able to define content in different areas of the document like `header`, `body`, `footer` while also creating presentational attributes like `color` or `image`.

```
KF.Document = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  documentAttributes: DS.hasMany 'documentAttribute'

KF.DocumentAttribute = DS.Model.extend
  attrKey: DS.attr 'string'
  attrValue: DS.attr 'string'
  document: DS.belongsTo 'document'
```

`Document.documentAttributes` returns a `DS.ManyArray` so in order to render it I could do the following:

```
{{#each da in documentAttributes}}
  <p>{{da.attrKey}} - {{da.attrValue}}</p> <!-- returns: "header - this is my header" -->
{{/each}}
```

The problem is that I want to access the keys directly (using a proxy?) so I can bind the data directly like so:

```
{{textarea value=documentAttributes.header cols="80" rows="6"}}
<img {{ bindAttr src="documentAttributes.imageSrc" }} >
{{textarea value=documentAttributes.footer cols="80" rows="6"}}
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be to enhance an em view (for the brave maybe a component as well), or create a proxy, that receives a DocumentAttribute object and defines dynamically a property with name the value of the attrKey and return the value of the attrValue. You could achieve this with the following code ,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ehoxUVi/2/edit

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return createProxy(App.DocumentAttribute.create());
  }
});

App.DocumentAttribute = Ember.Object.extend({
  attrKey:"theKey",
  attrValue:"theValue"
});



 function createProxy(documentAttr){
  App.DocumentAttributeProxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.extend({
    createProp: function() {
      _this = this;
      var propName = this.get('attrKey');
      if (!_this.get(propName)) {
        return Ember.defineProperty(_this, propName, Ember.computed(function() {
          return _this.get('attrValue');
        }).property('attrKey'));
      }
    }.observes('content')
  });
  var proxy = App.DocumentAttributeProxy.create();
  proxy.set('content',documentAttr);
  return proxy;
}
```

**HB**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{attrKey}}
    <br/>
    {{attrValue}}

    <br/>
    {{theKey}}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get melc's solution to work with the DS.ManyArray returned by the relationship.

But his examples gave me some ideas and I did the following. Basically mapping the items through a "shortcut key" on the controller.

```
KF.DocumentsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('model', model)
    # make an `Object` to store all the keys to avoid conflicts
    controller.set('attrs', Ember.Object.create())

    # loop through all `DocumentAttributes` in the `DS.ManyArray` returned by the relationship,
    # get the `attrKey` from each item and make a shortcut to the item under `attrs` object
    model.get('documentAttributes').forEach (item, index, enumerable) -> 
      key = item.get('attrKey')
      controller.get('attrs').set(key, item)
```

The template, where *header* is the `attrKey`

```
{{input value=attrs.header.attrValue}}
```

Comment: If you initialize an array of proxies, as shown in the answer i provided, within the loop of documentAttributes and then use that array to render your template, it should work fine. Ofcourse the array of proxies would have to be stored in your controller as you store the attrs.